# Evaluate Groovy/Grails Code in variable when printing it in GSP

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I have a GSP page containing different input elements related to a specific context.
For example I can display a textfield for usecase A, but not for usecase B (short version, it's very complex actually)

For this I have a domain object, which is normally populated with plain static HTML. But now I need to add dynamic data, like this:

```
def field = new InputField()
field.code = '<input type="text" name="foo" value="${currentUser.name}" />'
// or: field.code = '<option value="1"><g:message code="someCode"/></option>'
```

This code is stored in database. It will be rendered later on in GSP:

```
<g:each in="${InputField.findAllBySomeCondition(...)}">
    ${it.code}
</g:each>
```

This will print the input element, but instead of evaluating the dynamic code (`${currentUser.name}`) it is just printed as plain text.

Unfortunately I can't change the whole process, there are over 3000 different input elements stored already, but none of them are dynamic.

Is there a way to tell Grails to evaluate code within the variable before printing it?

edit: I'm using Grails 2.2.4

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using ' for the string, not ". When using ' the result is a String, not a GString with variable evaluation.

Try changing to:

```
field.code = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"foo\" value=\"${currentUser.name}\" />"
```

or use the triple version """ to avoid escaping:

```
field.code = """<input type="text" name="foo" value="${currentUser.name}" />"""
```

Comment: hm sorry I guess my question was not clear enough. `code` is stored in database and read later when rendering the page